# Expiration Date Format Stripe API in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I have a custom form for collecting card info. I'd like to have the expiration date in two separate fields for MM and YYYY. I've added the two fields with a forward slash embedded in the middle however when I try to complete a transaction it is returning an invalid card now even if I enter valid credit card numbers, listed here https://stripe.com/docs/testing. I originally had the expiration date set to one field and it was working fine. Did I go wrong somewhere? Thanks in advance

```
var stripeCard = STPCard()

if self.expMonth.text.isEmpty && self.expYear.text.isEmpty == false {

let expMonth = UInt(self.expMonth.text.toInt()!)
let expYear = UInt(self.expYear.text.toInt()!)

//Get Stripe card info token

stripeCard.number = self.creditCardField.text
stripeCard.cvc = self.securityField.text
stripeCard.expMonth = expMonth
stripeCard.expYear = expYear


}

var underlyingError: NSError?
stripeCard.validateCardReturningError(&underlyingError)
if underlyingError != nil {
    self.handleError(underlyingError!)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional on top is ambiguous and could mean "if month is empty and year is not empty". Thus, `stripeCard` will not be populated as expected.

But breakpoints into your code and check if the variables hold the values you expect.